# Python concurrency first result ends waiting for not yet done results

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing

What I wish to do is Move on... after the first True, not caring about not yet finished I/O bound tasks. In below case two() is first and only True so the program needs to execute like this:

```
Second
Move on..
```

NOT:

```
Second
First
Third
Move on...
```

---

```
import concurrent.futures
import time


def one():
    time.sleep(2)
    print('First')
    return False


def two():
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Second')
    return True


def three():
    time.sleep(4)
    print('Third')
    return False


tasks = [one, two, three]
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    for t in range(len(tasks)):
        executor.submit(tasks[t])

print('Move on...')
```

Comment: Multiprocessing but the outcome is the same, it waits untill all functions are done. I need to gracefully exit those still waiting tasks. I also try daemon vs. non-daemon threads.. but not really sure if it'll help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `with` statement is not what you want here because it waits for all submitted jobs to finish. You need to submit the tasks, as you already do, but then call `as_completed` to wait for the first task that returns true (and no longer):

```
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
futures = [executor.submit(t) for t in tasks]
for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
    if f.result():
        break
print('Move on...')
```

Comment: This doesn't really "move on". You have no code following the `print('Move on...')` statement so you would expect the program to immediately terminate, but it will not until functions `one` and `four` complete, which will take approximately another 3 seconds.

Comment: @Booboo I have no code following `print('Move on...')` because it's just an example. If you added such code, it'd run just fine, while one() and three() executed in the background - which I understood was the goal. The OP wanted the program to "move on", which mine does, not to exit immediately.

Comment: Look at the OP's question again re expected output: The OP does not  even want to see 'First' and 'Third' print out, which by necessity I take to mean functions `one` and `three` prevented from finishing executing. What you say about not being held up if you had additional code following your print('Move on...') executing right away is true enough. But if that additional code didn't require 3 seconds of wall time to run, your program termination would needlessly be held up waiting for functions `one` and `three` to complete.

Comment: @Booboo It's unclear whether the provided output is the beginning of the program or the whole program. You seem to assume that the program is expected to terminate at the point where it prints **move on**, which I would find strange ("move on" normally means move on to other things, not exit). Let's see what the OP will say.

Comment: B.I.G. I was wondering for over a year about that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` is that once tasks are submitted, they will run to completion so the program will print 'Move on...' but if there is in fact nothing else to do, the program will not terminate until functions `one` and `three` terminate and (and print their messages). So the program is guaranteed to run for at least 4 seconds.

Better to use the `ThreadPool` class in the `multiprocessing.pool` module which supports a `terminate` method that will kill all outstanding tasks. The closest thing to an `as_completed` method would probably be using the `imap_unordered` method, but that requires a single worker function being used for all 3 tasks. But we can use `apply_async` specifying a callback function to be invoked as results become available:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import time
from threading import Event

def one():
    time.sleep(2)
    print('First')
    return False


def two():
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Second')
    return True


def three():
    time.sleep(4)
    print('Third')
    return False

def my_callback(result):
    if result:
        executor.terminate() # kill all other tasks
        done_event.set()

tasks = [one, two, three]
executor = ThreadPool(3)
done_event = Event()
for t in tasks:
    executor.apply_async(t, callback=my_callback)
done_event.wait()
print("Moving on ...")
```